# Parse the number of shares in a string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string like "ABC will issue 1,600,000 shares next week.". Problem statement: I need to extract the number of shares from a string - the number of shares can be identified by the fact that it's followed by the word "shares". Is it possible to do that?

I've tried using the regex `'^(?=.)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)?(\.\d+)?$'`. The code is `re.search(<regex>, <string>)` but this only works when the string is just the number and nothing else. As soon `<string> = "1,000,000 shares"`, it returns `None`. Would appreciate any help!

There is another problem: If I remove the `^` and `$` anchors, then the regex pattern starts matching `''` as well, so a string like `"common shares"` may return `"common"`.

Comment: Your regex is explicitly anchored to the start and end of the string. If that's not the behaviour you want, don't do that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That runs into another problem but I should've mentioned that in the question. Will edit now

Comment: All of your pattern is optional, so yes it can match empty strings.

Comment: Use `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?` or `(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)`

Comment: `[\d,]+(?= shares)` this will match any combination of digit and `,` comma.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Will your regex patterns not report incorrect results on string "01,345,23 shares", ie, on an incorrectly formed number? Testing these regex patterns on regex101 reports two matches: "01,345" and "23". Also, it does not check for the presence of the word "shares".

Comment: Aha, so 1) no invalid numbers, 2) must be followed with `shares`  - use `(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*shares?\b)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Much better :-))

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure, he has wrong in this case, he needs to remove the anchor and dollar symbol.

Comment: @user9343456 you can try the simple mask to extract your inputs, I think this working well. ```(?i)\b((?:\d{1,},?){1,})\s?shares?\b```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex extracts the number of shares accurately from the string:

```
import re 

string = 'ABC will issue 1,600,000 shares next week 219,123,123 apples'
pattern = r'\b([\d,]+) shares\b'
print(re.findall(pattern,string))
```

**Output**

```
['1,600,000']
```

This essentially says:

1. From the beginning till the end this string must be
2. A digit followed by , repeated any number of times
3. Followed by a space, which is followed by the word shares

You also include the capturing group `()` to only see the number in your output and not the number followed by the word `shares`

Also:

```
import re 

string = '1,000,000 shares'
pattern = r'\b([\d,]+) shares\b'
print(re.findall(pattern,string))
```

**Output**

```
['1,000,000']
```

However, this approach assumes that all the numbers before the word `shares` are valid because it will also recognise numbers like `1,,,,000,000` or `1,0,00,,00,0` which are obviously not valid.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
keyword = 'shares'
test_string = 'ABC will issue 1,600,000 shares next week'
split_string = test_string.split()
print(split_string)
if keyword in split_string:
    index = split_string.index(keyword)
    assert index > 0
    shares_string = split_string[index-1]
    shares_string = shares_string.replace(',', '')
    nbr_shares = int(shares_string)
    print(nbr_shares)
```

Comment: Code will fail on the string "common shares".

Comment: Code will also report 123434 for the string "no 01,234,34 shares in this text", an incorrectly formed number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*shares?\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xk1Lwq/1).
*Details*:

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `(?<!\d[.,])` - no digit and a `.` or `,` char immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` - one to three digits followed with zero or more occurrences of a comma and three digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `(?=\s*shares?\b)` - immediately on the right, there must be zero or more whitespaces and `shares` or `share` with a word boundary after.